# Very +ed as adjustive

Tags: word-usage

e.g. It's very interesting.
     => **I'm very interested.**

But it sounds odd to me. I'd always use
**I'm interested very much.** instead.

I'd like to know if it's ok to say that.

Comment: May be more of a question for ELL - English Language Learners.

Comment: "I'm very interested" doesn't sound odd to me, but the other phrase does.

Comment: No, it's not standard phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing odd about "very interested". In fact, it's sounds more natural than "interested very much".  You may be very interested to look at the [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+interested%2C+interested+very+much&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20interested%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterested%20very%20much%3B%2Cc0) which indicate that "very interested" is very common and that "interested very much" is very depreciated.